# Add JAR to WAR's classpath without changing the WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, classpath, war

I deploy a WAR file in Tomcat.  In addition I have a JAR file.

Is it possible to make the classes in the JAR file available to services in the WAR file without changing the WAR file, or does it have be added to the WAR's WEB-INF/lib?

I've tried adding the JAR to `lib/`, but it doesn't work. Spring fails with org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException » java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError upon startup.

**EDIT**

I realized that I might have made myself an unsolvable and architectually ugly problem. Here's the thing:

- The WAR has a reference `<bean id="warService" class="com.war.Service" />`
- My JAR has a class com.mystuff.MyService that extends com.war.Service
- I have replaced the bean reference with `<bean id="warService" class="com.mystuff.MyService" />`
- Spring fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.war.Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could put it(your jar file) in your Tomcat root directory under `lib` folder. Chk this out :

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

**Per your edit**

1. Something is wrong with your jar
2. You have mistaken the fully qualified class name in your application context

I've happen to have `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin` jar in my `lib` folder. And just for test I've put this in my application context :

```
<bean id="driver" class="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

Worked as charm, check those two cases above

Comment: I've tried adding it to lib/, but it doesn't work.  Spring fails with org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException » java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError upon startup.

Comment: @neu242 I updated the question, can you show more code if still not working

Comment: The jar file works great when I put it in WEB-INF/lib/ in the WAR.  I'll see if I can provide a better example, but it's good to know that it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tomcat's lib directory but all jar added there has been shared for all app in your server.

Answer (score 0):

While not recommended, you could use the Tomcat "Common" classloader for this scenario.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html