# Unsatisfied Link Error While adding library my web project

Tags: java, web, netbeans, opencv3.0

I configured opencv 3 with netbeans successfully. All of my java desktop projects with opencv are working fine. Now I created a web application that use open cv components. While loading native library It shows the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path

I added opencv 300.jar file in my classpath and dll file is pointed using Djava.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think, to use jar file in your web application you need add it to war files (because in most webframework, web application should use war instead of jar) (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918957/4318868, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10481288/4318868, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5467530/4318868 and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opencv Java exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840758/opencv-java-exception)